# iPhone custom cells - transparent label background

Tags: iphone, label

Picture is worth more than a thousand words :)

[image]

Here is the code:

```
// Initialization code
        UIView *myContentView = self.contentView;
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"bg_top.png"];
        UIImageView *imageview = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: image];
        self.backgroundView = imageview;
        [imageview release];
        self.label = [self newLabelWithPrimaryColor:[UIColor blackColor] selectedColor:[UIColor redColor] fontSize:15.0 bold:YES]; 
        self.label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft; 
        [myContentView addSubview:self.label];
        [self.label release];
```

```
    self.textField = [[UITextField alloc] init];
    [self.textField setTextColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
    self.textField.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:13.0];
    //self.textField.secureTextEntry = YES;
    [self.textField setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeEmailAddress];
    myContentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [myContentView addSubview:self.textField];
    [self.textField release];
```

The question is how to remove that ugly white background from labels and make them transparent.

Comment: We need to see newLabelWithPrimaryColor:  Also, your  memory management seems wrong.

Answer (score 6):

Or alternatively:

```
self.label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the Background color with:

```
[self.label setBackgroundColor: [UIColor colorWithWhite: 1.0f alpha: 0.0f]];
```

or set the Alpha value to 0

```
[self.label setAlpha: 0.0f];
```

Hope that does the trick.

Comment: An UIColor instance already exists to do that: [self.label setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

Comment: Beside the clear color mentioned, setting the alpha will fade away the complete label.

Answer (score 0):

Just to sum things up. Based upon all your responses, the best solution is:

```
[self.label setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```